# Concurrent limited consumers using goroutins and channels

Tags: go

I've  tried to reproduce "approach that manages resources well is to start a fixed number of handle goroutines all reading from the request channel." from [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) and found

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

The idea is simple: have 1 queue and 1 results channels and several limited number of "workers".

My code is [in Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cBzq9bXq7Z)

```
queue := make(chan *Request)
result := make(chan int)
quit := make(chan bool)
go Serve(queue, quit)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    req := Request{i, result}
    queue <- &req
}
close(queue)
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("Finished %d\n", <-result)
}
fmt.Printf("All finished\n")
quit <- true
```

Function Serve:

```
func handle(queue chan *Request) {
    for r := range queue {
        //process(r)
        fmt.Printf("Processing %d\n", r.i)
        r.r <- r.i

    }
}

func Serve(clientRequests chan *Request, quit chan bool) {
    MaxOutstanding := 2
    // Start handlers
    for i := 0; i < MaxOutstanding; i++ {
        go handle(clientRequests)
    }
    <-quit // Wait to be told to exit.
}
```

What is wrong? Or may be there is simplier solution for implementing limited number of workers that process requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result channel isn't buffered, so each send blocks the goroutine until something receives the result. So after the first two items are processed, the two handler routines are waiting for their results to be received. But the code to receive work items isn't running yet, so they're stuck. Then main() tries to send the next work item, and the handlers aren't ready to receive it so main() is now stuck too.

One way to fix it is to start a goroutine to receive results in the background before you queue the work items. Here's a version of your code that receives the results in the background, plus makes `main()` wait until all results have been received and handled: http://play.golang.org/p/_CKn3CxQFc.

In your example, you can know when it's safe to quit just by counting results received. But if a situation comes up where you need to figure out when you're done and counting is not enough, then 1) each worker can signal when it's done, 2) `Serve` can close the result channel once all workers signal done, 3) your result-handling goroutine can send a `quit` to `main()` when all the results have been handled. There are lots of variations on that; you can see code at http://play.golang.org/p/12wZbm0rxa

Comment: Wow... so simple! Only one sentence completely explains issue: "so each send blocks the goroutine until something receives the result." Thnx.

Comment: Small question: May be there is a some component that I can use for such kind of tasks? For example for DB queries it is really good - limit number of concurrent executing DB queries, etc. So it would be really great to use some component with limited number of "executors"

Comment: There probably are some, but I don't have enough info to make recommendations unfortunately.

Comment: Found one implementation: https://github.com/otium/queue Could be useful for others who also interested in this topic.